# guardian:I have set "ANONYMOUS_USER_ID",but still get an ImproperlyConfigured error

Tags: python, django

I set ANONYMOUS_USER_ID in "/projectname/projectname/settings.py"

ANONYMOUS_USER_ID=-1

But it guardian.conf.settings raise ImproperlyConfigured when I use syncdb.

raise ImproperlyConfigured("In order to use django-guardian's "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: In order to use django-guardian's ObjectPermissionBackend authorization backend you have to configure ANONYMOUS_USER_ID at your settings module

[I also post this question on google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=zh-CN&fromgroups#!topic/django-users/44T9JhzOXcs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. reload server
2. check possible typo for `ANONYMOUS_USER_ID`
3. ensure the settings file is actually used and `ANONYMOUS_USER_ID` is the output of inside `./manage.py diffsettings`

Comment: I want to define a UserProfile class for "AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE".So I use "from userena.models import UserenaBaseProfile" and define a subclass :`class UserProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):    pass`. But "from userena.models import UserenaBaseProfile" cause problem. I don't why.

Comment: When I import  userena.models.UserenaBaseProfile or its subclass, I get the same error.

Comment: in settings.py ,I use "import userena.models.UserenaBaseProfile". And then when I use "diffsettings" and "syncdb" ,I get ImproperlyConfigured error.

Comment: Maybe I should ask: how to set "AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE"?  `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE="somemodel"` ?

Comment: @supei  something like `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE='userena.UserenaBaseProfile'` . You could  customize `UserProfile` in one of your app's models.py and set it in settings.py like `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE='yourapp.UserProfile'`. Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#auth-profiles

Answer (score 0):

> "/projectname/projectname/setting.py"

use settings.py instead of setting.py

Comment: Update now.It is "/projectname/projectname/settings.py". It was a typo.